# How to check the queries running in the sessionid in marklogic

Tags: marklogic

Is there a way we can see what queries are running using the session number from the logs?
Is there an api or a function in which if we put the session number it will provide us the whole query details like what query was it and which user was running it ?

Comment: I don't know that I've ever seen a session number in the logs. Which log file - access/request/error - are you referring to? And how are you getting that into the log file? I didn't see anything in Auditing; perhaps you're using a trace event? Also, I didn't see anything in the JS/XQY APIs when searching on the word "session" that would get what you're looking for.

Comment: yes I am talking about a trace event. Is there a way we can see from the history the entire query that a user might be running at a particular time ?